# React: How to add conditionally rendered extra options from child components (2 levels down) into state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, conditional-rendering

I have created a form as per the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/rlmv6ojjyn

In the SOW Type section there are three checkboxes. On clicking the checkboxes the user has access to further options (have not created these yet but the first option will require a set of drop-downs, the third option exposes a new checkbox (on clicking the first), which will (on click) will then expose some textarea boxes for the user to submit text.

I have got to this point as per the code in 'SOWType.js' (shown below) which is a child of 'PdfGenFormContainer.js'.

I have an object 'componentList' (inside SOWType.js) which is used with conditional rendering to display the relevant sub-component on relevant checkbox selection)

My question is, how do I include the user selections from these sub-components in state. The object 'componentList' is in the child component so how does all this get communicated to the state in the parent? (so it is all included when the form is submitted)?. Does 'componentList' need to sit in the parent somehow? (how would this work?)

Is my only option to use redux to get this done or can it be simply done in just React?

SOWType.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ProdSOWExtOptions from "./ExtendedOptions/ProdSOWExtOptions";
import TeradataExtOptions from "./ExtendedOptions/TeradataExtOptions";
import CustomProfExtOptions from "./ExtendedOptions/CustomProfExtOptions";

class SOWType extends React.Component {
  componentList = {
    ProductSow: <ProdSOWExtOptions type={this.props} />,
    "Teradata Customer SOW": <TeradataExtOptions />,
    "Custom Professional Services SOW": <CustomProfExtOptions />
  };
  render() {
    // console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor={this.props.name} className="form-label">
          {this.props.title}
          <h6>{this.props.subtitle}</h6>
        </label>
        <div className="checkbox-group">
          {this.props.options.map(option => {
            return (
              <label key={option}>
                <input
                  className="form-checkbox"
                  name={this.props.setName}
                  onChange={this.props.controlFunc}
                  value={option}
                  checked={this.props.selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1}
                  type={this.props.type}
                />
                {option}
                {this.props.selectedOptions.indexOf(option) > -1 ? (
                  <h5>{this.componentList[option]}</h5>
                ) : (
                  " "
                )}
              </label>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SOWType;
```

Comment: Typically with pure React, the answer is to elevate state to the highest necessary level - in this case SOWType (if I'm understanding correctly). Then you can just pass state to each of the child components in only one level.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. The highest level is 'PdfGenFormContainer.js' (so all form data is available when the form is submitted), SOWType is a child component, which, when implemented, will have 3 x sub-components of it's own (one of which will then have it's own subcomponent). So this will mean a number of levels, will this mean performance issues or is this setup to small for this to be an issue?

Comment: React is perfectly happy with state being passed down two levels, you shouldn't see any performance issues. However, it's not uncommon in forms that eventually you will move towards a single united state for all form data to solve problems like this. Personally, I use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to store and access form state.

Comment: By single united state are you talking about Redux? I think React Context is the more recent alternative isn't it? Sounds like it could be the way to go i'll take a look, thanks

Comment: "Single united state" means rather than creating and accessing state as and when you need it, your form data is united in a single location, with a common method for accessing and updating each piece of form data throughout forms. Context has been around for a while, but is now a very usable alternative for creating global state to redux.

Comment: Great, sounds like this is what i need i will investigate further, thanks for clarification